# Atom Snippets for tex files

Tags: coffeescript, atom-editor, code-snippets

I have a .tex file to which I want to add snippets. I have tried the following

```
'.source.tex':
  'console.log':
    'prefix': 'Hello'
    'body': 'Hello World!'
```

but it doesn't seem to work. (I have added this to my snippets.cson document on Atom).

Does anybody know what should be in the place of   "tex" in ".source.tex" in order to have the snippet work on a tex file?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer to my question. I had to write "Editor: Log Cursor Scope" in the Command Palette whilst having my cursor in the tex file which gave me the desired scope which is "text.tex.latex". The code then becomes

```
 '.text.tex.latex':
    'console.log':
      'prefix': 'Hello'
      'body': 'Hello World!'
```

and seems to work.